# initMap is not a function Google Maps Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I know this question has been asked. But I still can't get past it.
I am simply trying to get googlemaps API loaded in js fiddle. I cannot get past the error:initMap is not a function.
My jsfiddle here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebehrens/mp7j7gy0/53/)

My code:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 2
    });
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
      <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

When I have the  function initmap(){} (with brackets) the map does not load and I get the error.
When remove the `function initmap{}`and just:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: 34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 2
});
```

The map loads, however I still get the error:

initMap is not a function

It might have something to do with a callback. I have not written javascript in a while. But I just need to get past this error. Thanks

Comment: Is that a mistake in copying or you didn't close `initMap` properly?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mp7j7gy0/59/) of how it works.

Essentially place your function above the call to `Google API`

```
<script>
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: 34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 2
        });
    } // close function here
    </script>
    <script async defer
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDieZ7uAY4DPdT3Z4fp4KtykHl6dWryYdw&callback=initMap">
        </script>
```

Also the function wasn't properly closed.

Answer (score 11):

#### TL;DR

In the fiddle, you have a syntax error in not closing the `iniMap()` with `}`. Besides, the function is defined after the DOM loads. To fix this:

- set load type to wrap in `<body>` or `<head>`
- fix syntax error

[image: fix]

Here's how to deal with these.

#### Global scope

Place `initMap` in the global scope. do not wrap the function definition within a private or anonymous scope like

```
(function(){

function initMap(){
    //
}

})();
```

#### DOM onload

Define the function in the `<head>` if possible. or at least before loading the API in `<body>`. And never define `initMap` after the dom completely loads like `window.onload` and `document.addEventListener('ondomready', callback)`

Good practice

```
<script>
function initMap(){
  //
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Bad practices:

`window.onload`

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  function initMap(){
     //
  }
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

And

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('ondomready', function(){
  function initMap(){
     //
  }
});
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Or `$(function(){ })` if you are using jQuery

```
<script>
$(function(){
  function initMap(){
     //
  }
});
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling initMap before it was declared.

https://jsfiddle.net/mp7j7gy0/60/

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY"> </script>

var initMap = function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 2
    });
}

initMap()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for an answer in many forums, but I just found in my code there was a lost ';'. After deleting the ';' everything worked well.

I know it's not the best answer but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this problem too, but in my case the culprit seems to be mod_pagespeed.

I think it modifies the order of scripts in the page, thus previous solutions did not work. I managed to solve it by dynamically adding the Map's `script` tag.

```html
<script>
    function initMap() {
        // some code
    }

    // dynamically add your map
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap";
    tag.defer = true;
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using leaflet.js and Google gave me this as my default script

```
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCL6DiC25wgfa9oZKOn6TovyDgHWDnQLeo&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Basically just remove the Callback Query String Parameter because leaflet is supposed to call it.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCL6DiC25wgfa9oZKOn6TovyDgHWDnQLeo"></script>
```