# error InvalidValueError

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this error to load my page : 
[image]

This error appears from time to time, I do not see where it comes from  you have an idea?
For more readability I remove the style and the position of my zone.

```
        var map;
        var infoWindow;

        function initMap() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: {
              lat: 48.862569,
              lng: 2.281208
            },
            mapTypeId: 'terrain',
            styles: [ // styles]
          });

          // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
          var zone = [// zone];

          // Construct the polygon.
          var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: zone,
            strokeColor: '#ff9800',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            fillColor: '#ff9800',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
          });
          bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

          infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        }

    function showArrays(event) {
      var vertices = this.getPath();

      var contentString = '<b>Bermuda Triangle polygon</b><br>' +
        'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
        '<br>';

      // Iterate over the vertices.
      for (var i = 0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
        var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
        contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
          xy.lng();
      }

      // Replace the info window's content and position.
      infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
      infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

      infoWindow.open(map);
    }
    function showArrays(event) {
  var vertices = this.getPath();

  var contentString = '<b>Bermuda Triangle polygon</b><br>' +
    'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
    '<br>';

  // Iterate over the vertices.
  for (var i = 0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
    var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
    contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
      xy.lng();
  }

  // Replace the info window's content and position.
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

it's all my function but I have to say more detail is I do not know what to write.
it's all my function but I have to say more detail is I do not know what to write.
it's all my function but I have to say more detail is I do not know what to write.

Comment: Is your script loaded before gmaps' ?

Comment: I have update question

Comment: In the HTML itself, where do you load your script and where do you call the google-maps-api script ? Yours must be loaded first...

Comment: My script is in bottom HTML. I have script google API before my script to maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load Google Maps Api after your script

```
 <script>
  // Your code - ie: function initMap(){}  
 </script>
 <script async defersrc="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't properly formatted , you have an `Unexpected '}'` at line 12

```
styles: [ // styles]
     } // this is extra
```

Please validate your code using [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Also place your function above the call to Google API, like this :

```
<script>
function initMap() {
...
...
}
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourKeyHere">
</script>
```

Refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065766/initmap-is-not-a-function-google-maps-javascript) for some worthy ideas